# Firebase Crashlytics is not working in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to get all crash details on Firebase crashlytics dashboard. But I am not getting any kind of crash report on dashboard. I have done all the settings which required but I am not getting any crash reports.

I am getting this error on firebase crashlytics dashboard:

[image]

**Run script:**

[image]

[image]

**Debug setting:**

[image]
[image]

**Environment Variable**

[image]

**PodFile**

[image]

I am not able to understand that what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Remove DSYM folder path from debug setting and input files it works with "FirebaseCrashlytics/run" or with DSYM.

Comment: You can also follow this guide to manually upload your missing dSYM files. Once the dSYM files are uploaded, your crashes will be symbolicated and will show up on your crashlytics dashboard.